# spring-boot application startup failure

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have been working on a long-time spring-boot project. As of last week, the project started failing to execute. 
The initial error `Banner$Mode` has been fixed by updating starter parent version. However now I am getting

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 
'account.name' in value "${account.name}"
```

In this case, although I run the application with a profile, I see in the console output

```
INFO  [AccountApp] No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

(I am posting everythng that is spring related)

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

 <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jackson.version>2.9.0</jackson.version>
        <projversion>1.0</projversion>
        <buildnumber>undefined</buildnumber>
        <buildclassifier></buildclassifier>
    </properties>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

At this point it is essential to state that besides the pom, all the configuration and the application start worked smoothly. That's why I focused on a dependency based approach.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: First, don't truncate stack traces. Second, you're using the Spring Boot parent but then *explicitly* overriding with an outdated version of Spring.

Comment: you mean <spring.version> tag ?

Comment: and i have just posted the part that I thought could be useful

Comment: As pointed out by chrylis, first remove the `<spring.version>` property from your POM and then clean your question to only feature the problem you're getting then. All other issues might be compatibility issues since you're trying to Boot/Framework incompatible versions together

Comment: Are you missing the value in your application.properties?

Comment: no as I said the project was working smoothly until last week

Comment: Looks like you've edited this, but what is the value of `spring-boot.version`? And why do you have an old version for `spring-boot-starter-log4j`?

If you're going to use the spring boot parent pom, i'd highly recommend not specifying the versions of the spring artifacts in your pom and just using the version as defined in the parents. otherwise you're going to continue running into incompatible version mismatches like you're seeing now

Comment: spring-boot.version is 1.5.6.RELEASE
i understand and applied your suggestion.
in order to check, i have excluded log4j dependency, still problem prevails

Comment: "I run the application with a profile". How have you done that? Also, what's the connection between running with a profile and `account.name`? Are you using profile-specific configuration? A [minimal, complete, verifiable example](/help/mcve) would be useful here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments.
It turns out the update from `spring-boot` from `1.2.5` to `1.5.6` also includes a syntax change for application properties, meaning the `${account.name}` variable has to be declared as `@account.name@` 
Application started running smoothly after this change.